# Would it be possible to use web services from a Cobol program?

Tags: web-services, integration, communication, cobol

We have some COBOL programs in our financial applications which need to interact with some of our backend systems. One of the available interfaces is through a web service. Can a program written in Cobol make requests to a web service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Microfocus](http://www.microfocus.com/) provide a tool called Enterprise Server which allows COBOL to interact with web services.

If you have a COBOL program A and another COBOL program B and A calls B via the interface section, the tool allows you to expose B's interface section as a web service.

For program A, you then generate a client proxy and A can now call B via a web service.

Of course, because B now has a web service any other type of program (command line, Windows application, Java, ASP etc.) can now also call it.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used COBOL but from quick Google search it looks like it's possible.

[This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-webservicesrpg/#N10154) looks like it'll help, and talks about integrating webservices with cobol through c code.

Comment: Yes - but the problem here is that it doesn't allow Java, ASP, C# etc. which probably constitute the vast majority of web services these days.

Answer (score 1):

What platform is this on? IBM's CICS supports webservices invokationnn from cobol program via EXEC CICS INVOKE.

Answer (score 0):

I know I can write a WebService with Delphi and call a COBOL DLL or
call a Delphi dll to comunicate with webservice.

Right now Im writing a webservice client, it will be a DLL, and Ill call from old COBOL systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have and are using CICS, it has built-in mechanisms for that. But assuming you can't use that for some reason, you can build an HTTP client using the IBM TCP/IP 'EZASOKET' modules.

I work for a company with a z/OS system running mostly COBOL, batch (JCL) and CICS. To call webservices, we wrote a module to implement HTTP 1.0 using TCP/IP. With modules

- EZASOKET

  - GETHOSTBYNAME
  - SOCKET
  - CONNECT
  - WRITE
  - FCNTL
  - READ
  - CLOSE
  - SELECTEX

supplementary modules:

- EZACIC04 translates EBCDIC to ASCII
- EZACIC05 translates ASCII to EBCDIC
- EZACIC06 convert character to bit mask
- EZACIC08 decode IP address

Since I wrote this for my company, I can't just give out the code. But for reference, it took me 3 days to write the module (plus a little debugging later), and that was with an example to start with that did a partial hacky way of doing it.

You will need to read through IBM's references to know how to use the EZA modules.

- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.halc001/sampcs.htm

Answer (score -1):

ibm is now trying to implement a technology called embedded websphere with java.
ibm belives this is the only way to give the life to mainframes.